# JPA insert issue - OneToMany/ManyToOne with EmbeddedId

Tags: spring, jpa, orm, eclipselink

I've an issue where parent is generating multiple insert statements thereby having challenge with saving child. Code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PARENT")
public class Parent implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @EmbeddedId
        private ParentPK id;

        @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
        private String firstName;

        @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
        private String lastName;

    // bi-directional many-to-one association to ParDepend
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="parent", cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval=true)
    private List<ParDepend> parDepends;

    //getters, setters, add (for parDepends), remove (for parDepends)

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Borrower other = (Borrower) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}

@Embeddable
public class ParentPK implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @SequenceGenerator(name = "parSeq", sequenceName = "PARENT_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "parSeq")
    @Column(name="PAR_SK_SEQ")
    private long parSkSeq;

    @Column(name="PAR_REV_NUM")
    private long parRevNum;

    //getter, setters

    //JPA generated equals and hashcode
}

@Entity
@Table(name="PAR_DEPEND")
public class ParDepend implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private ParDependPK id;

    private BigDecimal age;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Parent
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="PAR_REV_NUM", referencedColumnName="PAR_REV_NUM"),
        @JoinColumn(name="PAR_SK_SEQ", referencedColumnName="PAR_SK_SEQ")
        })
    private Parent parent;

    //getters, setters

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        BorrDepend other = (BorrDepend) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}

@Embeddable
public class ParDependPK implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="PAR_SK_SEQ", insertable=false, updatable=false, nullable=false)
    private long parSkSeq;

    @Column(name="PAR_REV_NUM", insertable=false, updatable=false, nullable=false)
    private long parRevNum;

    @SequenceGenerator(name = "parDependSeq", sequenceName = "PAR_DEPEND_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "parDependSeq")
    @Column(name="SEQ_NUM")
    private long seqNum;

    @Column(name="REV_NUM")
    private long revNum;

    //getter setter

    //JPA generated equals and hashcode
}
```

I'm using dozer to convert UI returned data to JPA entity mapping. Then using Spring Repository to save and flush Borrower entity. It is generating borrower sequence twice and inserting nulls for borrower, instead of actual value. My assumption is that actual values are in memory to be inserted with first sequence, while second sequence will null data is getting inserted. Any suggestions on issue with JPA mappings? I do not see dozer an issue as logs shows JPA entity is property created as

{parent=Parent [id=ParentPK [parSkSeq=0, parRevNum=0], firstName=ABCD, lastName=XYZ, parDepends=[ParDepend [id=ParDependPK [parSkSeq=0, parRevNum=0, seqNum=0, revNum=0], age=31]]]}

JPA Ecliselink version 2.5.0-RC1
Spring Data JPA framework version 1.7.1.RELEASE

Please, let me know of any other information required for this question.

Edit: update dozer logs.

Comment: Database structure cannot be changed as it is being used by many other applications. Need a solution with existing restrictions.

Comment: why are you using a sequence value within a composite PK?  The sequence should make that single field unique, with no need for the other fields.  This is likely part of the problem, and will make your foreign keys unnecessarily complex as well.

Comment: This is existing DB structure that cannot be changed. Rationale given to me by DBA are sequence are used as Identifier along with revision number to track revisions on particular record. Unfortunately I've to leave with this DB structure.

Comment: You show parent and ParDepend, but talk of a borrower entity in your problem description.  Using your model, You must first persist and flush a new Parent so that its identifiers are set so you can manually set the ParDepend embeddable pk with the foreign key values. Or you can look into JPA 2.0 which allows setting a relationship to be part of a primary key or mapsId

Comment: @Chris - I'm not able to find documentation on eclipselink mapsId to support composite PK. Do you have any pointers? Logs updated from Borrower to Parent details.

Comment: the MapsId javadoc has one http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.0.2/javax/persistence/MapsId.html but i'll look for better ones later